# Using malloc with structures and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I am kinda new to C and I am trying to understand the use of malloc() with structures and pointers. Here's a snippet of a programme I am trying to write

```
typedef struct
{
    char *id;
    char *ocup;
    char cj[15]; //data to fill the vector
} T1;

typedef struct
{
    T1 *a1;
    T1 *a2;
} T2;

T2* Aloc(int mp)
{
    T1 *p,*s;

    T2 *af = (T2*)malloc(sizeof(T2));
    if(af == NULL)
        return 0;
    af->a1 = (T1*)malloc(sizeof(T1) * mp);
    if(af->a1 == NULL)
        return 0;
    // trying to go through the freshly created vector
    // but without success 
    for(p = af->a1, s = p + mp; p < s; p++)
        af->a2 = p;
    return af;
}

// mp = size of the struct
```

`T1 *a1` is the address start of a vector

`T2 *a2` is the end of it (...or it may end wherever i want in the vector)

If I try to compile the above code, the compiler freezes. I ran out of ideas. What am I doing wrong? :(

thank you!

Comment: Check the initialization and termination condition of the for cycle

Comment: You mean, the compiler freezes?

Comment: You are treating `mp` as the number of structures, not as the size of one structure.

Comment: How are you compiling your code? What command are you using and what is your syntax?

Comment: `for(p = af->a1, s = p + mp; p < s; p++)
        af->a2 = p;` The loop is completely senseless (the code in the loop body is (almost) loop invariant, only the rhs of the '=' changes.

Comment: Apart from the madness of the for loop that simply assigns what should be a closed-function evaluation to a single target (did you really intend to repeatedly assign to af->a2?), try this in your for-construct: `for (p = af->a1, s = af->a1 + mp; p < s; p++)`. I'm very curious to see if your compiler continues to choke on it.

Answer (score 1):

Other than code that seems very difficult to read and is likely to cause memory leaks, I'm going to stick my neck out and say this code should run without "freezing".

According to your question, it freezes during compilation, which would mean there is a problem with your compiler. While that could be related to the code being compiled, the fix is needed for the compiler not your code.

If you misspoke and the freezing occurs during run time, then you need to more carefully analyze where the freezing is occurring as I'm not convinced it's within this code alone. Most compilers these days come with a debugger. You'd be doing yourself a great favor by learning to use it.

Comment: The compiler freezes. Edited to be more specific. If i pull out the for, it doesn't freeze anymore..so that is the problem. I have no idea why, though.

Comment: Then please see my comment above. It would be difficult for us to tell you what's wrong with the compiler, not the least of reasons is that we don't even know what compiler you are using.

Comment: Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 I guess I will take a closer look later, can't concentrate anymore. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear: Under *no* circumstances should the compiler freeze no matter what code is being compiled. If the code is invalid, the compiler should indicate an error. If it freezes, then you have a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Jonathan Wood said I think you have a bad compiler, the compiler should never lock up or crash. A compiler doesn't even run your code, it looks at it to make sure nothing is wrong with it. If there is something wrong with your code and the compiler is working properly it should just spit out a nice error for you.

Solution: your compiler is bad, get a new one.

for windows: MinGW (Just compiler, but very easy to use with Eclipse)

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/

for mac: Xcode (IDE + compiler)

- https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

hope this helped!